# Is it possible to include csv file as part of python package

Tags: python-2.7, csv

Is it possible to include a csv file as part of python package?

I am creating a package and want some default config files which are imported at runtime.

I know I can store as a list or other structure in a .py file, but this will break the pattern I'm building against.

Answer (score 16):

This can be done in a two-step process, as detailed [here](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html).

You need one file in the root of your source, `MANIFEST.in` which reads:

```
include path/to/yourfile.csv
```

and you also need to add `include_package_data=True,` to the `setup()` function in `setup.py`.
Tried and tested.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you may use a specific module more than an "homemade version" to store configuration.
In your case: 
The Python standard library includes the [ConfigParser module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html), which handles ini-style configuration files for you.