# how to add csv files where installing packages with pip install in python?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I spent significant time, finding solution to this one problem :

My setup.py is as follow :

```
install_requires=install_requires,
python_requires='>=3.6.5',

include_package_data=True,

#### CLI
scripts = scripts,
```

However, when pip install -e .  , it does not copy into MYpackages/ the *.csv, *.txt files.
How to add it ?

Following ressources were checked:

[Is it possible to include csv file as part of python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531476/is-it-possible-to-include-csv-file-as-part-of-python-package)

https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+package+data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the links above do not mentionned, we need to this extra line
in setup.py :

```
package_data={'': ['data/*.csv']},
```

and add in MANIFEST.IN File

```
recursive-include YourPackage/data/*.csv
```