# How to include a csv file in my package in PyPi?

Tags: python, module, package

This is the first time I'm creating a python package. I follow all the instructions in this [text](https://medium.com/@joel.barmettler/how-to-upload-your-python-package-to-pypi-65edc5fe9c56), which was very well written and I was able to replicate every step without any issue.

Thus, I created a local directory with the following structure:

```
mypackage/
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
        mypackage.py
    LICENSE.txt
    README.md
    setup.cfg
    setup.py
```

Next, I follow these steps:

1. Push the directory to [github](https://github.com/lucascr91/cartpy)
2. Create a new release
3. Update setup.py file
4. run `python setup.py sdist`
5. run `twine upload dist/*`

And proceed to install my package using `pip`. It works finely

However, when I tried to import it I got the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File counties_1872_1991.csv does not exist: 'counties_1872_1991.csv'
```

Then I search for a while and found this two questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531476/is-it-possible-to-include-csv-file-as-part-of-python-package)). Folowing the instructions in the answers to each question, I did:

1. Create a MANIFEST.in file and add the line `include counties_1872_1991.csv`
2. Edit the `setup.py` file and add `package_data={'cartpy': ['counties_1872_1991.csv']},include_package_data=True` to the function setup

Unfortunately, this didn't work for me and I cannot say what I am doing wrong here. I thought is something related to absolute and relative paths, then I tried every possible combination but it didn't work either.

How can I include the csv file in my package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access data in package subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779495/access-data-in-package-subdirectory)

Comment: It did. Sorry, I didn't see this question in my earlier research. Thanks!